# Setting XML attribute regular expression pattern in JAXB?

Tags: xml, regex, jaxb

Is there a way to specify a regular expression pattern on an `@XmlAttribute` somehow through annotations? Is there a way of doing this besides validation through an external schema?

Comment: The MOXy JAXB implementation might have an annotation for this. It would bind you to a specific implementation, but its annotations seem highly useful and worth that investment. Blaise Doughan will probably pipe in with an answer soon. In the meantime, check this: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php

Comment: What are you trying to do? Associate regexp to do what? Match attribute name? Validate the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an implementation of JSR-303 which provides both annotations and an XML config file for specifying rules for bean validation:

- http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303